# commandLink does not work on the first click

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, icefaces

I've found some questions that seem related to this one, but none describes exaclty what is happening to my web app.

Here it goes: it's a very simple app, with a left menu bar, a header and a central panel to show some texts. The menu bar has a lot of `commandLink`s which will define which page is going to be loaded in the central panel. The strange problem is that none of these links work when the page is just loaded. In other words, my first click does nothing. From the second click on, the links work.

I'm using JSF 1.2 and IceFaces 1.8.1. This is the code snippet with the first commandLink (all of the others are similar):

```
<f:view>
    <html>
    <head>
    <ice:outputStyle href="./xmlhttp/css/rime/rime.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <ice:form id="nav_form" partialSubmit="true">
        <ice:messages />
        <ice:panelGrid columns="1" width="152">
            <ice:panelCollapsible expanded="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <ice:panelGroup>
                    <ice:outputText value="Cliente"
                        style="font:bold 12px;color:#484848" />
                </ice:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
                <ice:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <ice:commandLink actionListener="#{cliente.defineText}" 
                        action="cliente" id="consulta">
                        <ice:outputText value="Consulta" />
                    </ice:commandLink>
```

Important remarks:

- I'm using some includes, but there are no nested forms.
- There is no data model. At the time the app is only a prototype, with links and static texts.
- I'm using regular html `<table> ... </table>` tags to design the main page, even though I know this is not necessarily the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same answer as this one: [page does not refresh after an action is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900925/page-does-not-refresh-after-an-action-is-called)

I removed the JSF 1.2 Apache Myfaces and substituted by the Sun RI jars.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you have set unique **Ids** manually to each of commandlink, commandSortHeader, etc.
Not needed to eliminate any jars from the classpath!

Comment: (a) OP is already doing that; (b) you don't have to set IDs manually in Facelets unless you have cross-references in the XHTML or you have Java code that relies on them; (c) the remark about JARs and classpath seems completely pointless.