# page does not refresh after an action is called

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, icefaces

I have `commandLink` with an `actionListener` that calls a method to change the value of `text`. The same `commandLink` has an `action` that reloads the page. When I click the `commandLink`, the `actionListener` is called. But the `action` only is completed --showing the updated value of text-- when I refresh the browser. Why isn't the `outputText` being automatically updated?

Some code:
**home.jspx**

```
(...)
<f:view>
 <table id="main_table">
 <tr><td width="160px"><jsp:directive.include file="./logo.jspx" /></td>
      <td><jsp:directive.include file="./header.jspx" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td width="160px"><jsp:directive.include file="./vertical_navigation.jspx" /></td>
      <td align="center"><ice:outputText value="main" /></ice:outputText></td></tr>
 </table>
</f:view>
(...)
```

**customer.jspx** is the same, but the value of the `outputText` is `#{customer.text}`
**vertical_navigation.jspx**: many command links like the following:

```
(...) 
<ice:form id="nav_form"><ice:panelGrid columns="1">
    <ice:panelCollapsible expanded="true">
    <f:facet name="header"><ice:panelGroup>
      <ice:outputText value="Customer" />
     </ice:panelGroup></f:facet>
     <ice:panelGrid columns="1">
      <ice:commandLink actionListener="#{client.defineText}" 
      immediate="true" action="customer" id="list">
       <ice:outputText value="List" />
      </ice:commandLink>
(...)
```

the bean:

```
(...)
public String text;
public void defineText(ActionEvent evt) { 
 text = ... some text related to the link
}
public String getText() {
 return text;
}
```

Well, everything works fine, except that I have to refresh the page when I click a link so that the value of `text` is updated. I put some `System.out.println()` satatements inside the bean methods and noticed that the `defineText` method is called whenever I click a link. But the `getText` is called only after a refresh. The output is like this:

```
// click the link "list"
called defineText for link list
// click the link "new"
called defineText for link new
// click the link "external"
called defineText for link external
// refresh the broswer
called getText // this will show the updated value of "text" for the link "external"
// click the link "new"
// refresh the broswer
called defineText for link new
called getText // this will show the updated value of "text" for the link "new"
```

I'm working with **JSF 1.2** and **IceFaces 1.8.2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a sollution. I removed the JSF 1.2 Apache Myfaces and substituted by the Sun RI jars. If anyone can explain why it worked, I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with IceFaces, but try to remove `immediate="true"` from your command link - with standard `h:commandLink` it could cause the problem.

Comment: I have tried it before. The getText method is called (page is refreshed, good) but the defineText method is not called anymore, which means that the actionListener does not work -- bad. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Its about the cycle and how the events are handled.

from my experience, two ways to fix it:

1) queue the event (check the different type of events) until its time to update the values.

2) work around by trapping with another tag